# login not working on my rails twitter clone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I'm on Charles Max wood tutorial on the twitter clone. I'm getting this error `RuntimeError in HomeController#show`

```
undefined method `all_flits' for nil:NilClass
```

but when I try it on the console the method works

with raise session.inspect I get

```
{"return_to"=>"http://localhost:3000/sessions", "session_id"=>"2baca34a681d6a9e259991481891f7bf", "_csrf_token"=>"pKRBBE3m4+T+aTeBBFvqDsEsKxPaWG5AxF3hBiWlV2E="}
```

I use Ryan Bates nifty generator to login. Which has been working until now. I don't know which error I got in the show method.

The URL for login is              `http://localhost:3000/login`
the error I'm getting is on URL   `http://localhost:3000/sessions`
on login I'm supposed to go to the `http://localhost:3000`
which corresponds to the 'home#index'

HomeController

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required
  
  def index
    @flits = current_user.all_flits
    @last_flits = current_user.flits.last
  end
  
     def show
        @user =  User.find_by_username(params[:username])
        @flits= @user.all_flits
      end
  
   def toggle_follow
        @user =  User.find_by_username(params[:username])
        if current_user.is_friend? @user
          flash[:notice] = "You are no longer following @#{@user.username}"
          current_user.remove_friend(@user)
        else
          flash[:notice] = "You are now following @#{@user.username}"
          current_user.add_friend(@user)
        end
        redirect_to show_path(@user.username)
       
     end
end
```

Show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= image_tag @user.gravatar_url, :align => "top" %> <%= @user.username %></h1>

<%= form_tag  toggle_follow_path do  %>
  <% if current_user.is_friend? @user %>
     <%=h submit_tag "Following"  , :class => "button" %>
  <% else %>
     <%=h submit_tag "Not Following"  , :class => "button" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%=h render :partial => "flits_list", :locals => { :flits => @flits }%>
```

model User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # new columns need to be added here to be writable through mass assignment
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  
  # gravatastic
  include Gravtastic
  gravtastic 
  has_gravatar :size => 50
  

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :prepare_password

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :allow_blank => true
  validates_format_of :username, :with => /^[-\w\._@]+$/i, :allow_blank => true, :message => "should only contain letters, numbers, or .-_@"
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 4, :allow_blank => true


  has_many :flits, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  
  
  
  
   def add_friend(friend)
      friendship = friendships.build(:friend_id => friend.id)
       if !friendship.save
         logger.debug "User '#{friend.email}' already exists in the user's friendship list."
       end
   end
   
     def remove_friend(friend)
           friendship = Friendship.find(:first, :conditions  => ["user_id = ? and friend_id = ?", self.id, friend.id])
           # friendship = self.friendships.find(:friend_id => friend.id)
           if friendship
             friendship.destroy
           end
         end
      
         def is_friend?(friend)
           return self.friends.include? friend
         end
      
      def all_flits
           Flit.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id in (?)", friends.map(&:id).push(self.id)], :order => "created_at desc")
      end
  
  # login can be either username or email address
  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    user = find_by_username(login) || find_by_email(login)
    return user if user && user.password_hash == user.encrypt_password(pass)
  end

  def encrypt_password(pass)
    BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pass, password_salt)
  end

  private

  def prepare_password
    unless password.blank?
      self.password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.password_hash = encrypt_password(password)
    end
  end
end
```

route file

```
Flitter2::Application.routes.draw do
  
  root to: 'home#index'
  match 'user/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user

  match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup

  match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout

  match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login
  
  match '/:username',       to: 'home#show', as: 'show'
  
 match '/:username/toggle_follow', to: 'home#toggle_follow', as: 'toggle_follow'
  

  resources :sessions

  resources :users

  resources :welcome
  
  resources :flits
end
```

Ryan bates controller_authetication module

```
module ControllerAuthentication
  def self.included(controller)
    controller.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?, :redirect_to_target_or_default
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user
  end

  def login_required
    unless logged_in?
      store_target_location
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first log in or sign up before accessing this page."
    end
  end

  def redirect_to_target_or_default(default, *args)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default, *args)
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end

  private

  def store_target_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

Gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem "mocha", :group => :test

gem 'faker'
gem 'populator'
gem 'gravtastic'
```

Comment: jump into the rails console and search for the User with an id of 2, check it exists

Comment: Your right it's not there but the user i'm calling for got the id 12 .How come is the app checking for id = 2

Comment: in your show action try  @user =  User.find(params[:id])

Comment: yeah still got the same result 
Couldn't find User with id=2

Comment: It's wierd because when  i use firefox instead of Safari (Where i'm getting the error ).i'm getting redirected to the login page instead of login

Comment: this may happen because cookies are saves on safari with user_id =2, delete your cookies from firefox and check again it should  redirected to the login page

Comment: thank you Now i'm getting redirected to the login form  with a flash message "You must first log in or sign up before accessing this page" .but  how come when the user is rigth . the login use to work and now it's not.

Comment: @user =  `User.find_by_username(params[:username])` will return `'nil'` if id doesn't exist. It doesn't return `'Couldn't find User with id=2'` which would be returned by `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

Comment: But when i replace `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])` by  `@user = User.find(params[:id])` i' still getting the same result getting redirected to the login page again.

Comment: Check the params you are getting, accordingly you have to write the query.

Comment: `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jkjNtK0mVS/AXJLgyqX1ryNZzARY38xoxrVktLu03aw=", "login"=>"will", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in", "username"=>"sessions"}` I'm sorry i'm a bit lost what do you mean by writing the query

Comment: You don't have id in your params. Make sure your username is 'sessions' or not as you have passed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20743/discussion-between-skip87-and-venkatk)

Comment: i'm sorry i'm a a newby in programming 
but how do i make sure of that

Answer (score 0):

Would you like tell me how did you get "current_user" variable ? I guest that something wrong in this. I don't see any line in your code to store the user after logging in successfully.

Comment: it's From the nifty generator by ryan bates. i'm adding the file

Comment: It's in controller_authentiaction

Comment: Your routes.rb is confusing. 

  `match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup``match 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout`  `match 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login`  

Will be confused with

`match '/:username',       to: 'home#show', as: 'show'`

Comment: and how do i fix this do i have to delete or rename some path

Comment: You can wrap it to "user/:username" or do a trick by setting signup, logout, login to another method and use GET method for "/:username" (I don't recommend that way)

Answer (score 0):

i have also got this problem then i can solve it some steps
1.priority order for routes

```
match '/edit_current_user' => 'users#edit', :as => :edit_current_user, :via => :POST
match '/signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup, :via => :GET
match '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy', :as => :logout, :via => :GET
match '/login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :login, :via => :GET
```